# How to send request to remote URLs?

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, axios

How can I send an axios request to the right url?

I am trying to make a GET request from my android ionic react app:

```
axios.get("192.168.178.88:8080/api/user/me")
    .then(response =>response.data)
```

I do not get the results expected from the endpoints and get the following logs

```
D/Capacitor: Handling local request: http://localhost/
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
D/Capacitor: Handling local request: http://localhost/static/js/main.c1f587ce.js
D/Capacitor: Handling local request: http://localhost/192.168.178.88:8080/api/user/me
```

I'd like and expect request to

> http://192.168.178.88:8080/api/user/me

instead of

> http://localhost/192.168.178.88:8080/api/user/me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not forget to add `http` to the URL in the axios request:

```
axios.get("http://192.168.178.88:8080/api/user/me")
        .then(response =>response.data)
```